# Why is php sending a application/x-gzip file after using soap?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, debugging, soap

**What went before**

I was busy adding a new method to a soap api. After testing the web application that uses the soap api one method did not work. I get no exceptions and I do not have a clue on what is going on.

**What is going on**

When I call the soap method like this:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
    ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 120);

    $soap = new SoapClient('http://***********.nl/**********.svc?wsdl', array('exceptions' => TRUE));   

    $array = array(
        'appkey' => "b4bf874r64gffrefrt4t334j63rertyh0"
    );
    $res = $soap->getUserList($array);


    /*
    $array = array(
        'user' => "test"
    );
    $res = $soap->userExist($array);
    */

    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r($res, true);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I get this:

[image: A gzip document]

A gzip file instead of a html file including my print_r content. When I open the file it looks like this:

[image: the gzip document opened in codelobster]

I have no idea why this is happening. The php version is 5.3.27 which looks quite up to date and I can not find any bug reports that describe this problem.

**What I tried to solve this**

I have tried to restart the soap service and I searched my c# code for any errors but is seems to be alright. Also the php code looks quite alright. When I call the out commented soap method I get the expected result.
Even if I made some coding mistakes php should not do this right!?

**My question**

Is there someone who knows what is going on and how I can fix this. My thoughts are that this is a weird php bug. All the other soap calls give me a valid response.

**Update**

I used nusoap:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://**************.nl/**************.svc?wsdl', 'wsdl');
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->decode_utf8 = false;
$param = array('appkey' => "b4bf874r64gffrefrt4t334j63rertyh0");
$result = $client->call('getUserList', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($result, true);
echo '</pre>';
```

gives same result so I think the problem is not in the soap extension.

Comment: have you tried gzip deflating it to see what it says?

Comment: Not yet... I have never done that before I am looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Looks like the Soap endpoint is returning gzip data.

Comment: `<?php echo gzdeflate($gzippedString); ?>`

Comment: I opened the gzip file with winrar and it contains a file which I opened with notepad++ which looks like the html I expected. But why is php sending it this way is this a php/soap bug??

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it**

There was no problem with either the soap api or the PHP code. It was a Malware issue. When inspecting I saw that the console gave some weird errors. It tried to load javascript from superfish.com.

> www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=viktczu&userId=37078fed3d574a308b5e298c9a3fd837&CTID=cE4IwJSsmtycAc&ver=13.1.4.31

When googling this I found out that this is considered to be malware and I removed it from my pc.

Other ajax response (which had no soap at all) also started to fail. Now I know that was because of this malware. After removal everything worked again.